# Acess object's attribute inside another object using Javascript / D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to define an id to each edge of a network.

```
(...).enter().append("svg:line")
        .attr("class", "edge")
        .attr("id", function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            return "still a test";
        });
```

The code prints:

```
Object { label: "MB2 (pp) NEK6", source: Object, target: Object, value: 1 }
```

Source and Target attributes have objects with attributes (they are nodes of the network), including the attribute "id".
But when I use:

```
console.log(d.target.id);
```

It returns "undefined" and when running:

```
console.log(d.target);
```

it returns a number, i think it is related to the attribute "index" of the object stored in d.target.

I don't understand why d returns an object with object (OK) and d.target seems to return a number (Not OK) and, so, d.target.id does not return the target id.

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using the force layout or something similar and your original data contains the IDs of source and target for each link. What happens when you run the force layout is that those numeric references get resolved into the actual node objects.

When you do the `console.log()`, this hasn't happened, meaning that the original IDs are still there, not the objects.

The reason that the log shows you something different is that the objects that are logged are resolved when you click on them to inspect the members. That is, `console.log()` is not showing what was there when it was logged, but what is there now that you look at it. By the time that happens, the source and target IDs have been replaced by the objects.

To fix, start the force layout before operating on the objects you want to log.